# When any why is it useful to have a descriptor's `__get__` method return another descriptor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, descriptor, getattr, getattribute

I had a container holding an object's methods, and possibly some descriptors. I wanted to test whether the descriptors had already been unwrapped or not by checking whether they had had a '**get**' method. To my surprise, the `__get__` method of a class-method returns an object which also has a `__get__` method. Do you know when this behavior is useful? Does it have something to do with overriding class methods in a derived class?

```
import inspect

class K:    
    @classmethod
    def cm(cls, a, b, c):
        pass

def get_attr_info(attr):
    try:
        sig = inspect.signature(attr)
    except:
        sig = None

    attr_info = [
        ('id ', id(attr),),
        ('type  ', type(attr),),
        ('hasattr ', '__get__', hasattr(attr, '__get__'),),
        ('hasattr ', '__call__', hasattr(attr, '__call__'),),
        ('SIG:  ', sig,)
    ]
    return attr_info

get_label = lambda tpl: ' '.join([str(x) for x in tpl[0:-1]]).ljust(20)

kinst = K()
cm = object.__getattribute__(type(kinst), '__dict__')['cm']

try:
    for idx in range(0, 5):
        info = get_attr_info(cm)        
        print('\n' + '\n'.join([get_label(tpl) + str(tpl[-1]) for tpl in info]))
        cm = cm.__get__(kinst, type(kinst))
except AttributeError:
    print(idx)
```

**The Output Is:**

```
id                  44545808
type                <class 'classmethod'>
hasattr  __get__    True
hasattr  __call__   False
SIG:                None

id                  6437832
type                <class 'method'>
hasattr  __get__    True
hasattr  __call__   True
SIG:                (a, b, c)

id                  6437832
type                <class 'method'>
hasattr  __get__    True
hasattr  __call__   True
SIG:                (a, b, c)

id                  6437832
type                <class 'method'>
hasattr  __get__    True
hasattr  __call__   True
SIG:                (a, b, c)

id                  6437832
type                <class 'method'>
hasattr  __get__    True
hasattr  __call__   True
SIG:                (a, b, c)
```

Comment: Are you asking specifically why `types.MethodType.__get__` exists, or are you asking the more general question in your title?

Comment: Also, consider that most non-data descriptors are going to return a plain-old function from `__get__`. See the pure-Python `ClassMethod` at the end of the the descriptor HOWTO for an example. And functions obviously have to be non-data descriptors or methods couldn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

The specific behavior you're seeing used to make sense because of unbound method objects. Back in Python 2, if you did

```
class Foo(object):
    def useful_method(self):
        do_stuff()

class Bar(object):
    useful_method = Foo.useful_method
```

`Foo.useful_method` would evaluate to an *unbound method object*, something similar to but slightly different from a function. Unbound method objects needed a `__get__` so `Bar().useful_method` would auto-bind `self`, just like if `Foo.useful_method` had evaluated to a function instead of an unbound method during the definition of `Bar`.

Unbound method objects and bound method objects were implemented with the same type, so bound methods shared the same `__get__` method unbound methods had. For bound method objects, though, `__get__` would just return the bound method object, as if no descriptor logic was involved.

Now that unbound methods no longer exist, the `__get__` method of method objects is superfluous, but it hasn't been removed.

Comment: I think there was some argument about it not being superfluous because "methods should continue to act like functions". Although that argument is probably spurious (their `__get__` may exist, but it doesn't do the same thing as a function's `__get__`; the interpreter never does this reflection; if an end-user wants to do this reflection they should be using `inspect` which will treat them as different in every way except for both being callable; etc.), without actually hashing the argument out in full, the default is always to err on the side of backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific question of why bound methods are descriptors (it should be obvious why `classmethod` objects are, right?), see [user's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50050148/908494).

---

For the general question of why non-data descriptors need to be allowed: it would be more painful to write them. After all, the most obvious way to write a non-data descriptor is often to just return a function. And functions have to be non-data descriptors, or methods wouldn't work, defeating the whole reason descriptors were added to the language.

For example, consider the "pure-Python `classmethod`" example in [the HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#static-methods-and-class-methods):

```
class ClassMethod(object):
    "Emulate PyClassMethod_Type() in Objects/funcobject.c"

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __get__(self, obj, klass=None):
        if klass is None:
            klass = type(obj)
        def newfunc(*args):
            return self.f(klass, *args)
        return newfunc
```

Or, more simply, consider `staticmethod`, which even in the builtin implementation just returns the function itself when bound.

Of course you could also implement any of these by building an object with a custom `__call__` method, and sometimes that's worth doing (e.g., you could implement `classmethod` with `partial`, or with something that acts like `partial`, in which case there'd be no reason to add `__get__`)—but when a function just works, why not use a function?

---

For the more abstract question of whether you could possibly find a use for this feature… Well, sure. Among the things you can do are:

- Create explicit 2.x-style unbound methods—that are then inspectable as methods, rather than as functions.
- Create "rebindable" methods as part of building a prototype object system. (Normal method objects just ignore their arguments in `__get__`, except for checking that either the second one is a type, or the second is `None` and the first is a type…)
- Create an object that mimics a function (rather than just a callable, the way methods, partials, etc. do), including being able to act as an unbound method, the result of a staticmethod, etc.

None of these are things you're going to want to do very often, but they're also not things Python has any reason to prevent you from doing.